# Why is there a white wire connected to multiple black wires in my light box?

Tags: electrical, bedroom

I have a total of four receptacles a ceiling fan and a light switch. My line voltage comes in from the first receptacle, then comes out at the ceiling fan, then is wire nutted to the three other receptacles and the light switch at the ceiling. I have a total of four 12/2 wires sticking out the ceiling where the fan used to be.

When I took the fan down There was one neutral wire wired to all of the hots I believe. Would the neutral come from the switch or somewhere else? The light switch controls the ceiling fan and three of the four receptacles.

Comment: Pictures would help a great deal

Comment: I removed your second question. As [we're a Q&A site](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) and not a discussion forum, multiples don't work well. Please post it as a new question if you like.

Answer (score 2):

It *goes to* the switch, technically. You have a typical switch loop where the white wire runs to the switch and returns as the black in the same cable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The white going to the switch should have a piece of black tape on it designating it as a hot on switch side and fan side,  if not be sure to add this for future reference.